# An attribute is not displayed in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I have an attribute **immobilier.ref** that is not displayed with twig
this is the code

```
                                    {% for immobilier in listImmobilier %}

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{ immobilier.id }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ immobilier.ref }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ immobilier.titre }}</td>
                                        <td><a href="{{ path('immobilier_show', { 'id': immobilier.id }) }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" style="display:block; text-align:center"></span></a></td> 
                                        <td><a href="{{ path('immobilier_edit', { 'id': immobilier.id }) }}">Edit</a></td>
                                        <td><a href="{{ path('immobilier_delete', { 'id': immobilier.id }) }}">Delete</a></td>
                                    </tr>

                                {% endfor %}
```

this is a photo of the table
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It(s fine now, it was because I have a function named ref in the entity

```
    /**
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 */
public function ref()
{
    $id = $this->getId();
    $operation = $this->getOperation()->getRef();
    $this->setRef($id.$operation);
}
```

I have changed her name and it work fine now.